# I need to learn about the map function in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react Can anyone show me a simple example where I can understand how the map function works. I need map function to iterate over an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a core Javascript method, not part of reactjs. Click through for some documentation, including an example.